# Finding maximum flow in a network with lower and upper capacities using igraph

Tags: r, graph, igraph, network-analysis

The R function `max_flow()` (package `igraph`) implements an algorithm for finding a maximum flow through a capacitated directed network. A basic example [here](https://henrywang.nl/maximum-flow-problem-with-r/) shows how it can be applied to a simple case.

In more complex cases, however, the capacities of arcs can be given as a range (a lower capacity and an upper capacity). I can't see that `max_flow()` can deal with these cases. (Or can it?) Is there a function/package that can?

Comment: Could you explain how the maximum flow using the ranges of capacities is different from the maximum flow using the upper bounds of the capacities?

Comment: @VincentTraag see this [crude quick slide](https://imgur.com/a/ML0KxEq).

Comment: Thanks! I'm afraid I miss the point though. The capacity in the example on the left is 3, not 5, and using 5 as the capacity, the maximum flow is equal to 5. Do you have a reference that explains it in more detail?

Comment: @VincentTraag see [here](https://imgur.com/a/eXH12qh).